# Multiple p-value in shapiro.test with R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, p-value

I want to get the p-value of multiple shapiro test. I want to test the normality of 20 (from 4 to 23) columns from a data frame called bladder, then i want to get the p-value of each one programmatically and store it, I'm trying something like:

```
ttest20<-apply(bladder[4:23], 2, shapiro.test)
pVals <- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(ttest20)){
pVals<- ttest20[i]$p.value
}
```

but the last line don't store all the p-value. 
Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the programming language? What do you expect? What do you get instead? "isn't working" is not a good question.

Comment: Store to `pVals[i]`, not `pVals`.

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the answer, here is it:

```
ttest20<-apply(bladder[,4:23], 2, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value)
```

This returns all the p-value from all shapiro.test